# Puma causes Ruby 3 Debug to show ANSI escape sequences when pressing arrow keys (Mac ZSH)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, ruby-debug, ruby-3

I'm on Mac OS 12.3.1 using Z shell.

When using the Ruby Debug gem (1.5) in Puma 5.6.4 with Ruby 3.0.0 the arrow keys do not work and instead print out the ANSI escape sequences (e.g. `^[[A`  for up). If I understand correctly, Puma is running on /bin/sh, which doesn't support the arrow keys.

Certainly I'm not the only one trying to debug a Rails 7 app on a Mac. Anyone else run into this and have a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem with `debug` gem. I found it is caused by `databasecleaner`.

My workaround is

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    #DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean_with(:deletion)
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    # DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :deletion
  end
  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    #DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :deletion
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    # DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
  config.before(:all) do
    # DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:all) do
    # DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```